# Handling `&#xA;` in Python

Tags: python, xml, encoding, beautifulsoup

## Problem Background:

I have an XML file that I'm importing into BeautifulSoup and parsing through.  One node has the following:

```
<DIAttribute name="ObjectDesc" value="Line1&#xD;&#xA;Line2&#xD;&#xA;Line3"/>
```

Notice that the value has `&#xD;` and `&#xA;` within the text.  I understand those are the XML representation of carriage return and line feed.

When I import into BeautifulSoup, the value gets converted into the following:

```
<DIAttribute name="ObjectDesc" value="Line1
Line2
Line3"/>
```

You'll notice that the `&#xd;&#xA;` gets converted to a newline.

My use case requires that the value remains as the original.  Any idea how to get that to stay? Or convert it back?

## Source Code:

#### python: (2.7.11)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #version 4.4.0
s = BeautifulSoup(open('test.xml'),'lxml-xml',from_encoding="ansi")
print s.DIAttribute

#XML file looks like 
'''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<DIAttribute name="ObjectDesc" value="Line1&#xD;&#xA;Line2&#xD;&#xA;Line3"/>
'''
```

Notepad++ says the encoding of the source XML file is ANSI.

## Things I've Tried:

- I've scoured the documentation without any success.
- ### Variations for line 3:

  ```
  print s.DIAttribute.prettify('ascii')
  print s.DIAttribute.prettify('windows-1252')
  print s.DIAttribute.prettify('ansi')
  print s.DIAttribute.prettify('utf-8')
  print s.DIAttribute['value'].replace('\r','&#xD;').replace('\n','&#xA;')  #This works, but it feels like a bandaid and will likely other problems will remain.
  ```

Any ideas anyone?  I appreciate any comments/suggestions.

Comment: You could replace them with some original strings before parsing, at the end treat those as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Just for record, first the libraries that **DO NOT** handle properly the `&#xa;` entity: `BeautifulSoup(data ,convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)`, `lxml.html.soupparser.unescape`, `xml.sax.saxutils.unescape`

And this is what works (in Python 2.x):

```python
import sys
import HTMLParser

## accept file name as argument, or read stdin if nothing passed
data = len(sys.argv) > 1 and open(sys.argv[1]).read() or sys.stdin.read()

parser = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
print parser.unescape(data)
```